# iOS 8 make statusbar black and not translucent

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-6, uistatusbar

So my status bar in my app currently looks like this:

[image: 1]

And I'd rather it look something like this:

[2 http://mojoimage.com/free-image-hosting-12/22iOS7_StatusBar-copy.png](http://mojoimage.com/free-image-hosting-12/22iOS7_StatusBar-copy.png)

So that it's black with white text. At the moment it doesn't work on this particular screen because the background isn't black. And I've already set the `Status Bar Style` in the pList to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

I'll also add that the View is the initial ViewController AND it doesn't have a `UINavigationController` embedded into it:

EDIT: This is not a duplicate because most of the other previous solutions are outdated already.

Comment: @ChrisSlowik nope, because those are responses from 2011, and no longer valid in iOS 8

Comment: yea you're right. You should set your status bar to light content and put a black view behind it. 21pt if i recall correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set it to light and then toss a view behind it. You'll also have to account for device rotation if you allow that in your app.
**Swift:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let statusBG = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 21))
    statusBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    view.addSubview(statusBG)
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *statusBG = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 21)];
    statusBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:statusBG];
}
```

Comment: But this is ugly on iPhoneX. How to solve it on iPhoneX?

Comment: This is an outdated design pattern and should be avoided on iOS11. Can't fix ugly. Check out the Human Interface Guidelines from Apple for more details on iPhone X Design. https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

Answer (score 0):

Because on iOS 6 or earlier, the status bar is not translucent, so It's better to do this based on the iOS version. In your `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    UIView *statusBarView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];
    statusBarView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:statusBarView];
}
```

where `SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO`:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

This will give you a status bar with black background and white text.

Answer (score 0):

in your AppDelegate applicationDidFininshLaunchingWithOptions method write below code.This helps to your all view controller.You don't need to add code in every view controller.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden=NO;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) 
{ 
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
  [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
  self.window.clipsToBounds=YES;
  self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
else
{
  self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
  [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
  self.window.clipsToBounds=YES;
  self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

Then you yourprojectName.plist give

```
Status bar is initially hidden is NO
View controller-based status bar appearance is YES
```